# PHP imap_search() BODY vs TEXT

Tags: php, imap

Does anyone know the difference between `BODY` and `TEXT` criteria in [imap_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php) ?

Description on php.net is very foggy and unclear

`BODY "string" - match messages with "string" in the body of the message`

`TEXT "string" - match messages with text "string"`

I've been testing both criteria and found no difference. Both looking for string in whole message.

The worst part (for me) is that both criteria looking for string also in message attachments. So if I have mails with 5mb *.csv files, `imap_search()` takes a lot of precious time.

I understand that `BODY` criteria should include attachments, because attachments are part of body. But using `TEXT` criteria I was expecting something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TEXT refers to anywhere in the e-mail: headers or body.
BODY refers to body, including attachments.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thanks! BTW is there any method/criteria to avoid search in attachments?

Comment: In standard IMAP no; it has no specific concept of attachments; just body parts.